# How do I make this even? L = {w ∈ {0, 1}* | n0(w) = 2n1(w) and |w| is even}

Tags: context-free-grammar

How do I make a CFG for this language?
I have S -> S1S0S0 | S0S1S0S | S0S0S1S | epsilon but I'm not sure how to make this even in length as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pure CS theory, which is a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

A grammar that disregards the constraint that |w| be even:

```
S -> 00S1 | 0S01 | S001 | 010S | 01S0 | 0S10 | S010 | 100S | 10S0 | 1S00 | S100
S -> SS
S -> epsilon
```

How do we force that |w| be even? Well, we can introduce a new symbol T to handle the case where |w| is odd, and simply do not allow T to produce epsilon.

```
S -> 001T | 00T1 | 0T01 | T001 | 010T | 01T0 | 0T10 | T010 | 100T | 10T0 | 1T00 | T100
S -> SS | TT
S -> epsilon
T -> 001S | 00S1 | 0S01 | S001 | 010S | 01S0 | 0S10 | S010 | 100S | 10S0 | 1S00 | S100
T -> ST | TS
```

Why does this work? Because if S generates strings of even length, and T generates strings of odd length, these productions maintain that property and account for all ways of going from even- to odd-length strings. Because we don't want to accept odd-length strings we don't let T be eliminated. We can derive 000011:

```
S -> 00T1 -> 0000S11 -> 000011
```

But we can't derive 000000111:

```
S -> 00T1 -> 0000S11 -> 000000T111 -> …?
```

The same basic idea would work with your grammar as well, but I leave that as an exercise since our grammar has more S's per string and would require lots of productions to account for combinations of S and T which produce even lengths.